# as3 friend invite by using StageWebView

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I start to invite friend by using `StageWebView` as following:

```
private function inviteFriends():void
    {
        var urlRequest:String = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?%20app_id=xxx&%20message=Let's%20play%20Movie%20Star%20Planet!&%20redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com";
        m_WebView = new StageWebView();
        m_WebView.stage = stage;
        m_WebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        m_WebView.loadURL(urlRequest);

        m_WebView.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, handleEvent);
        //m_WebView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleEvent);


    }

protected function handleEvent(_event:HTTPStatusEvent):void
    {
        trace (_event.type);
        trace (_event.status);
        trace (_event.responseURL);
    }
```

When I push send button in invitation page, the process will redirect to facebook.com.

So, if it possible to check that process is redirecting or not?

I try `Event.COMPLETE` but it call back when load invite complete.

I try to invite by using as3 facebook api, but I got the problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377853/invite-facebook-friend-in-as3).

Thank you.

Comment: why not use the facebook api?

Comment: I try but I can't invite by using `FacebookMobile` in as3. I posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377853/invite-facebook-friend-in-as3

Comment: Have you tried using the graph api, you should be able to call this from the as3 api:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572861/invite-a-friend-to-app-using-facebook-graph-api

Comment: you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992525/inviting-facebook-friends-in-air-app-for-ios

Comment: no i meant the link i posted. there are more links and a comment about sandbox mode.